# Grails services in abstract class

Tags: spring, grails, groovy, abstract-class

I have an abstract class that many classes extend. Everything is in `src/groovy`.

In my abstract class I would like to have a service injected that the child classes would inherit so I don't have to inject them in every single one.

```
abstract class Animal {

    def noiseService

    abstract Sound getSound()

}

class Dog extends Animal {

    Sound getSound() {
        noiseService.bark()
    }

}
```

In my resources.groovy:

```
animal(com.thepound.Animal) { bean ->
    noiseService = ref("noiseService")
}
```

This produced an error saying it couldn't instantiate the class because it is abstract, so I added this to the definition:

```
    bean.abstract = true
```

Now I no longer get an error, however the services are always null in my child classes. How can I get this to work?

Comment: Did you check this? http://stackoverflow.com/a/11458329/791406

Comment: Does that mean for all of my subclasses I have to declare them as a bean and `bean.parent = ref("animal")` ??

Comment: You can't instantiate an abstract class directly; the class would be unusable; `getSound()` would not work.

Comment: Correct. I want to instantiate Dog and call it there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I ended up doing.

I followed Burt Beckwith's post here http://burtbeckwith.com/blog/?p=1017 to create an ApplicationContextHolder class.

Then

```
abstract class Animal {

    def noiseService = ApplicationContextHolder.getBean("noiseService")

    abstract Sound getSound()

}
```

Now this works

```
class Dog extends Animal {

    Sound getSound() {
        noiseService.bark()
    }

}
```

I didn't have to put anything in resources.groovy for the `Dog` or `Animal` classes

Answer (score 0):

If you want to instantiate Dog, just do this:

```
noiseService(com.whatever.DogNoiseService) { bean ->
}

animal(com.thepound.Dog) { bean ->
    noiseService = ref("noiseService")
}
```

Comment: I have probably a dozen classes that inherit from `Animal`. This would mean I would have to duplicate this for every single one?

Comment: @JamesKleeh If you declare them as Grails services (in grails-app/service) there's no need to do that manually.

Comment: Yes I realize that, however I don't feel the work being done here fits the model of services. There isn't any persistence in any of the classes.

Comment: @SérgioMichels I usually take this approach, albeit my service configs are more complicated, and there's lot's of them, I prefer to centralize the wiring in `resources.groovy`

Comment: @JamesKleeh You don't have to, I was simply following your original approach. I use this method and none of my services use persistence; a service is whatever you define as a service. You can use convention over configuration and let grails figure it out without manually wiring the beans, but when things don't work it's harder to figure out why: http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/gettingStarted.html#conventionOverConfiguration

Comment: Ok if I move my subclasses into `grails-app/service` do I also need to move the abstract class?

Comment: Make sure the abstract class is somewhere on the source or library path, but if you're using convention over configuation, you should try and collocate the services in `grails-app/service`

Comment: @raffian I tend to prefer creating a grails plugin intead of resources.groovy.