# How can I access injected Grails beans in an abstract class method?

Tags: spring, grails

I have an abstract class that implements much of the functionality inherited by a large number of concrete classes that are registered as beans. The beans are defined with autowiring on.  For example:

```
abstract class MyAbstract {

    MyService myService
    MyBean myBean

    def doSomething() {
        def value = myService.something(myBean)
    }
}


class MyConcrete extends MyAbstract {
    def concreteField

    def doSomethingElse() {
         def value = myService.somethingElse(myBean)
    }
}
```

conf/spring/resources.groovy:

```
myConcrete(MyConcrete) { bean ->
    bean.autowire = true
    myBean = ref(MySpecificBeanImpl)
}
```

My Problem:

When I run the method doSomethingElse in a MyConcrete instance, everything works as expected and the myService and myBean values are filled in with the proper values by DI. When I execute the doSomething method in a MyConcrete instance, both the myService and myBean values are null. It appears that the DI values are not visible in the abstract method inherited by the subclass. That really sucks.

I can manually access the values using a context holder in the method or I can pass the values from the subclass to the abstract parent class using a modified method signature that accepts those values as parameters, but these are no good solutions. It completely breaks the usefulness of abstract class implementations and requires a lot of replicated code that I don't want to have to maintain.

Even worse, in my specific case, the value of myBean is actually different for each concrete class, explicitly wired in the resources.groovy file, so the generic holder approach doesn't work.

I've looked through a number of posts relating to this including [Grails services in abstract class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19435742/grails-services-in-abstract-class) without much result in figuring out what is going on. The abstract bean definition seems to be about abstracting the bean definition properties and doesn't have anything to do with abstract classes and subclass inheritance.

(1) Is this a limitation in the Grails/Spring DI support? 
(2) Is there something else I need to do wrt the abstract class?

Comment: have you defined the abstract class as an abstract bean in resources.groovy?

Comment: As I mentioned above, the abstract bean definition is more of a bean property template and doesn't really have anything to do with Groovy class inheritance -- at least that is what the doc says. I did try it for giggles, but it didn't do anything like what I wanted. As expected based on the documentation.

Comment: This works for me (grails 2.4.3). What doesn't make sense to me is that doSomethingElse works but doSomething not. If you call both methods on the *same* bean it is using the same member variables. Why would they be null for one method but null for the other method (unless there is some side effect that clears the members). Did you call both methods on the same object?

Comment: Yes, both methods are run in the MyConcrete instance. And yes, it is highly surprising the that values are null in the method inherited from the abstract base class. It breaks class inheritance and the useful code reuse that it provides. I surmise that injection occurs somewhere in the object lifecycle such that the injected values are only visible in the subclass provided methods. Very strange. I am running in 2.3.11 however, so I'll try a little test in 2.4.3 to see if it is different.

Comment: "I surmise that injection occurs somewhere in the object lifecycle such that the injected values are only visible in the subclass provided methods." - There isn't really any point in the lifecycle where DI could be done that would cause the behavior described here.  There has to be some other explanation.  Are you sure that you don't have any data hiding going on in your subclass that might be relevant?  Having runnable code which demonstrates the problem would make this a lot easier to understand.  I expect that the cause is something simple.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have left out some details and I have had to make some assumptions but I have created an app with something similar to what you are describing.  The project at https://github.com/jeffbrown/abstractbeanmethods contains the following and appears to work:

src/groovy/demo/MyAbstract.groovy
    package demo

```
abstract class MyAbstract {

    MyService myService
    MyBean myBean

    def doSomething() {
        myService.something(myBean)
    }
}
```

src/groovy/demo/MyConcrete.groovy

```
package demo

class MyConcrete extends MyAbstract {
    def doSomethingElse() {
         def value = myService.somethingElse(myBean)
    }
}
```

grails-app/conf/spring/resources.groovy

```
// Place your Spring DSL code here
beans = {
    myBeanImpl demo.MySpecificBeanImpl

    myConcrete(demo.MyConcrete) { bean ->
        bean.autowire = true
        myBean = ref('myBeanImpl')
    }
}
```

src/groovy/demo/MySpecificBeanImpl.groovy
    package demo

```
class MySpecificBeanImpl implements MyBean {
}
```

src/groovy/demo/MyBean.groovy

```
package demo

interface MyBean {}
```

grails-app/service/demo/MyService.groovy
    package demo

```
class MyService {

    def something(MyBean bean) {
        "Bean class name is ${bean.class.name} in MyService.something() method"
    }
    def somethingElse(MyBean bean) {
        "Bean class name is ${bean.class.name} in MyService.somethingElse() method"
    }
}
```

grails-app/controllers/demo/DemoController.groovy
    package demo

```
class DemoController {
    def myConcrete
    def index() {
        def sb = new StringBuffer()
        sb << myConcrete.doSomething()
        sb << " and "
        sb << myConcrete.doSomethingElse()
        render sb
    }
}
```

You may find some significant difference between something there and someting that you are doing.  If you can isolate a problematic scenario in that sample app, or provide a runnable version of your code then I will be happy to straighten it out for you.

Comment: Your assumptions are very reasonable. The application you provided runs as expected in my environment. The sample that I provided was a significantly simplified version of what I actually have running, so it appears that it is something to do with that complexity. In my actual code I have beans being registered in a plugin with reference dependencies in the application. I'll try to modify your example to emulate the more complex scenario I have and see if I can recreate it that way (rather than trying to pare down my application code). Thanks for taking the time to do this Jeff.

Comment: @SteveHole Understood.  One way or the other, if you can isolate any way to reproduce the behavior in an app that I can see, I will be happy to get it straightened out.

Comment: @JeffScottBrown this is still the best solution i have found for this kind of problem, thank you.
have any better, or more isolated solutions been added to grails in the past two years?

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem using `@Autowired` annotation

```
import grails.gorm.services.Service
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired

@Service(User)
abstract class UserService {

    @Autowired
    OrganizationService organizationService

    //...
}
```

Tested on Grails 3.3.5