# Grails 4 service not being injected inside Grails Data Service

Tags: grails, grails-4

This is about a Grails service injected into a **Data Service**. The problem is that the injected service is null at runtime. Here is an example.

```
class MessagingService {

    def sendEmail(String message) {
      ...
    }
}
```

```
interface IFlowService {
    ...
}

@Service(Flow)
abstract class FlowService implements IFlowService {

    MessagingService messagingService

    void sendFoo() {
        messagingService.sendEmail(message)
    }
}
```

`FlowService` and `MessagingService` both reside under `grails-app/services`.

When `FlowService` calls `sendEmail` there is an NPE because `messagingService` is null.

`MessagingService` is hand-written and is not associated with a domain.

This project uses Grails 4.0.10 and the issue occurred several times. When the usual Gails magic (i.e. injection) didn't work I solved the first one or two issues with kludges, you know, just to avoid getting stuck.

Now it seems to me the issue is quite predictable, it happens every time I write a service not associated with a domain. Did I miss something in the documentation? What is the appropriate way to handle this?

**Kludge:** To get around the issue I include a method `sayHi` in the problematic service. It just logs a debug message. I invoke `sayHi` from *BootStrap* to check that it works. It does, surprisingly. Then I add code in *BootStrap* to assign the service to the supposedly injected property in the service. [Shudder]

Comment: `FlowService` is abstract - you can only instantiate a subclass of it, I thought? IIRC subclasses of abstract classes need to be wired up manually anyway. If you remove the `abstract` keyword, does it work as expected?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/19452877/249327

Comment: Thanks, but my problem is MessagingService. FlowService uses a Grails idiom that generates a service. It works as expected. The app has over a dozen services. Most of them are based on the pattern that FlowService uses. In several cases they call each other with the intended result. (One has to be aware of circular dependencies, of course.)

Comment: https://github.com/grails/gorm-hibernate5/issues/202 may be relevant

Comment: That seems to be a different issue @JeffScottBrown. There the author is talking about injecting a data service in a `src/main` file

Comment: "That seems to be a different issue"  My mistake.  I thought the root cause was the same.  Sorry for the noise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to reproduce the same-

```java
interface IFlowService {

}
```

```java
@Service(Flow)
abstract class FlowService implements IFlowService {

    MessagingService messagingService

    void hello() {
        println "hello"
        messagingService.hi()      // <- NPE
    }
}
```

```java
class MessagingService {

    void hi() {
        println "hi"
    }
}
```

This seems to be a bug to be in Grails. But you can easily solve this (probably as a workaround) by just adding `@Autowired` in the service-

```java
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired

@Service(Flow)
abstract class FlowService implements IFlowService {

    @Autowired
    MessagingService messagingService

    void hello() {
        println "hello"
        messagingService.hi()      // <- No NPE
    }
}
```

It prints-

[image]

Comment: Tried and works. To me it's a solution, rather than a workaround. Great!