# Overriding Spring bean with using the parent properties

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, grails, groovy

I was wondering if it is possible to override a bean definition but using the parent bean's properties as is?

I'm using Grails 2.5.0 along with Spring Security Core 2.0-RC4. In the plugin's descriptor file i.e. `SpringSecurityCoreGrailsPlugin`, a bean `authenticationProcessingFilter` is registered as:

```
authenticationProcessingFilter(RequestHolderAuthenticationFilter) {
    authenticationManager = ref('authenticationManager')
    sessionAuthenticationStrategy = ref('sessionAuthenticationStrategy')
    authenticationSuccessHandler = ref('authenticationSuccessHandler')
    authenticationFailureHandler = ref('authenticationFailureHandler')
    rememberMeServices = ref('rememberMeServices')
    authenticationDetailsSource = ref('authenticationDetailsSource')
    requiresAuthenticationRequestMatcher = ref('filterProcessUrlRequestMatcher')
    usernameParameter = conf.apf.usernameParameter // j_username
    passwordParameter = conf.apf.passwordParameter // j_password
    postOnly = conf.apf.postOnly // true
}
```

Now, I want to use my own `authenticationProcessingFilter` which does something else before attempting login so I defined a class:

```
class CustomAuthenticationFilter extends RequestHolderAuthenticationFilter {

    @Override
    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws AuthenticationException {
        println "Overridden bean"
        return super.attemptAuthentication(request, response)
    }
}
```

(I'm just extending the parent bean class and for now added a print statement)

Now, I'm trying to use this class to replace the one defined by Spring plugin. So I wrote something like this in my `resources.groovy`:

```
beans = {
    authenticationProcessingFilter(CustomAuthenticationFilter)
}
```

When I fired my Grails app, it starts complaining that `authenticationManager must be specified`. So I searched for the problem and found some articles but that doesn't helped. (Articles [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4249978/overriding-the-bean-defined-in-parent-context-in-a-child-context), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5849192/springs-overriding-bean), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11457927/how-do-i-create-a-bean-in-resources-groovy-with-an-abstract-parent-bean) and [4](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-java)).

So I tried something like this to use the `parent` attribute:

```
beans = {
    authenticationProcessingFilter(CustomAuthenticationFilter) { bean ->
        bean.parent = ref('authenticationProcessingFilter')
    }
}
```

But the above code didn't worked also. I think it's possible via the `value="parent"` attribute when beans are defined with XML but I'm not able to get that done in Java way.

Do the only option I have is to redefine all the properties in my `resources.groovy` like:

```
authenticationProcessingFilter(CustomAuthenticationFilter) {
    authenticationManager = ref('authenticationManager')
    sessionAuthenticationStrategy = ref('sessionAuthenticationStrategy')
    authenticationSuccessHandler = ref('authenticationSuccessHandler')
    authenticationFailureHandler = ref('authenticationFailureHandler')
    // and other properties like so
}
```

or is there a cleaner way around it?